# How to add appendix into bookmark for tex4ebook?

Tags: bookmarks, tex4ebook

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass{amsbook}
 \usepackage{bookmark}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Hello}
 Hello

 \chapter{Hi}
 Hi

 \appendix
 \chapter{One}

 One

 \chapter{Two}
 Two

 \end{document}
```

The bookmark of the result generated by tex4ebook doesn't contain the appendices. What I want to say is that, in the bookmark, the appendices aren't shown. However, they are correctly shown in the ToC page. I wonder how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just updated `tex4ebook` with the appendix support, so the development version at [Github](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook) should work. This is your file rendered by Calibre:

[image]